# Remove Code from String and get Values

Tags: php

I want to remove this code

```
[gallery columns="2" link="none" ids="69,50" orderby="rand"]
```

from a string. The [gallery .....] is always the same and the ... changes. How can I do this? Then I want to save the ids value in another string. What is the most elegant way?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Regex will match the whole string to remove it, and will contain the ids in an extracted group:

```
/\[gallery .*?ids="(.*?)".*?\]/
```

This code should work:

```
$string ='test i am test lol [gallery columns="2" link="none" ids="69,50" orderby="rand"] me also!';
preg_match('/\[gallery .*?ids="(.*?)".*?\]/', $string, $matches);

echo $matches[1]; // prints the ids

$string = preg_replace('/\[gallery .*?ids="(.*?)".*?\]/', '', $string);

echo $string; // prints the cleaned string
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much! I did not find a good manual to understand this stuff: /\[gallery .*?ids="(.*?)".*?\]/. Can you tell me how it is called so I can search for it?